# imx6ul with Kernel 5.15.91: USB OTG not working

Tags: linux, usb, device-tree, imx6, usb-otg

I am using Yocto to build a custom system with the Kernel 5.15.91 on an i.mx6 Chip. Unfortunatley USB OTG never seams to work. With the following Device Tree I can get it into Device Mode, but it never switches to host mode:

```
/ {
    regulators {
        compatible = "simple-bus";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        reg_usb_otg1_vbus: regulator@2 {
            compatible = "regulator-fixed";
            reg = <2>;
            regulator-name = "usb_otg1_vbus";
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_usb_otg1_vbus>;
            regulator-min-microvolt = <5000000>;
            regulator-max-microvolt = <5000000>;
            gpio = <&gpio5 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
            enable-active-high;
            status = "okay";
        };
    };
};

&usbotg1 {
    dr_mode = "otg";
    status = "okay";
    disable-over-current;
    vbus-supply = <&reg_usb_otg1_vbus>;
};

&iomuxc {
    pinctrl_usb_otg1_vbus: usbotg1 {
        fsl,pins = <
            MX6UL_PAD_SNVS_TAMPER8__GPIO5_IO08  0x000000b9
        >;
    };
};
```

But as soon as I add anything remotely resembling OTG mode switching it stops working entirely.
For example adding `usb-role-switch`:

```
&usbotg1 {
    dr_mode = "otg";
    status = "okay";
    usb-role-switch;
    disable-over-current;
    vbus-supply = <&reg_usb_otg1_vbus>;
};
```

= FAIL

Or adding extcon with the ID pin:

```
/ {
    regulators {
        compatible = "simple-bus";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        reg_usb_otg1_vbus: regulator@2 {
            compatible = "regulator-fixed";
            reg = <2>;
            regulator-name = "usb_otg1_vbus";
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_usb_otg1_vbus>;
            regulator-min-microvolt = <5000000>;
            regulator-max-microvolt = <5000000>;
            gpio = <&gpio5 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
            enable-active-high;
            status = "okay";
        };
    };

    extcon_usb: extcon_iddig {
        compatible = "linux,extcon-usb-gpio";
        id-gpio = <&gpio1 00 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_usbotg1>;
    };
};

&usbotg1 {
    dr_mode = "otg";
    status = "okay";
    disable-over-current;
    vbus-supply = <&reg_usb_otg1_vbus>;

    extcon = <&extcon_usb>;
};

&iomuxc {
    pinctrl_usbotg1: usbotg1_id {
        fsl,pins = <
            MX6UL_PAD_GPIO1_IO00__GPIO1_IO00    0x0001b020 /* ID Pin */
        >;
    };

    pinctrl_usb_otg1_vbus: usbotg1 {
        fsl,pins = <
            MX6UL_PAD_SNVS_TAMPER8__GPIO5_IO08  0x000000b9
        >;
    };
};
```

= FAIL

I even tried to use endpoints in conjunction with the PTN5110 driver:

```
/ {
    regulators {
        compatible = "simple-bus";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        
        reg_usb_otg1_vbus: regulator@2 {
            compatible = "regulator-fixed";
            reg = <2>;
            regulator-name = "usb_otg1_vbus";
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_usb_otg1_vbus>;
            regulator-min-microvolt = <5000000>;
            regulator-max-microvolt = <5000000>;
            gpio = <&gpio5 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
            status = "okay";
        };
    };
};

&usbotg1 {
    dr_mode = "otg";
    status = "okay";
    disable-over-current;
    vbus-supply = <&reg_usb_otg1_vbus>;

    port {
        usb1_drd_sw: endpoint {
            remote-endpoint = <&typec1_dr_sw>;
        };
    };
};

&i2c4 {
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c4>;
    status = "okay";

    usb_pd: ptn5110@50 {
        compatible = "nxp,ptn5110";
        reg = <0x50>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_usb_pd>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio5>;
        interrupts = <5 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW>;
        wakeup-source;

        port {
            typec1_dr_sw: endpoint {
                remote-endpoint = <&usb1_drd_sw>;
            };
        };

        usb_con: connector {
            compatible = "usb-c-connector";
            label = "USB-C";
            data-role = "dual";
            power-role = "dual";
            try-power-role = "source";
            source-pdos = <PDO_FIXED(VSAFE5V, 2000, PDO_FIXED_USB_COMM | PDO_FIXED_DUAL_ROLE)>;
            sink-pdos = <PDO_FIXED(VSAFE5V, 2000, PDO_FIXED_USB_COMM | PDO_FIXED_DUAL_ROLE)
                                     /*PDO_FIXED(VSAFE5V, 3000, 0)
                                       PDO_FIXED(9000, 3000, 0)*/
                                     PDO_FIXED(12000, 3000, 0)
                                     PDO_FIXED(20000, 3000, 0)>;
            op-sink-microwatt = <10000000>;

            /*vbus-supply = <&reg_usb_otg1_vbus>;*/
            /*id-gpios = <&gpio1 00 (GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH | GPIO_PULL_UP)>;*/
        };
    };
};

&iomuxc {
    pinctrl_i2c4: i2c4grp {
        fsl,pins = <
            MX6UL_PAD_UART2_TX_DATA__I2C4_SCL   0x4001b8b0
            MX6UL_PAD_UART2_RX_DATA__I2C4_SDA   0x4001b8b0
        >;
    };

    pinctrl_usb_pd: usbpdgrp {
        fsl,pins = <
            MX6UL_PAD_SNVS_TAMPER5__GPIO5_IO05      0x0001b020 /* Alert Interrupt */
            MX6UL_PAD_SNVS_TAMPER9__GPIO5_IO09      0x0001b020 /* Fault Interrupt */

            MX6UL_PAD_GPIO1_IO00__GPIO1_IO00    0x0001b020 /* ID Pin */
        >;
    };

    pinctrl_usb_otg1_vbus: usbotg1 {
        fsl,pins = <
            MX6UL_PAD_SNVS_TAMPER8__GPIO5_IO08  0x000000b9
        >;
    };
};
```

= FAIL

And I tried all the permutations I could think of but nothing worked.
I hope that someone with a better understanding of the device tree might be able to help. We could even discuss compensation for your help.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution eventually? I am in a very similar situation with very similar hardware.